# Nested DIV's and z-index

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create this type of an overlapping by using z-index on divs:

[image: Nested DIV's and z-index]

However, if I set the z-index of the parent to a smaller number than z-index of the "non-child" element, the child stays at the back with it's parent too.
I'm wondering if there is any way to overcome this issue..

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this ? http://codepen.io/mudittuli/full/rEgkw

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code, but I believe you are using some of the DIVs as ancestors; try to use all of them separately. That example does what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Positioning test</title>
        <style>
            div { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; color: #fff; text-align: center; }

            #parent { z-index: 1; background-color: red; left: 100px; top: 20px; }
            #not-child { z-index: 2; background-color: green; left: 140px; top: 40px; }
            #child { z-index: 3; background-color: blue;  left: 70px; top: 60px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">Parent</div>
        <div id="not-child">Not-child</div>
        <div id="child">Child</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah as I can see from your answer, the "non child" is still on the top. What I want to get as the result is just like the image (non-child in the middle)

Comment: Just use the appropriate z-indexes: 1 for Parent, 2 for Not-Child and 3 for Child. I'm worried to see you've not figured that out. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I've tried that, and I could not make it work that way.. That's why this topic is here at the first place.